# Receive data posted with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this code for sending data with ajax to a update.php page

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#modify").click(function() {
    var a = $("#a").val();
    var b = $("#b").val();
    var c = $("#c").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        a: 'a',
        b: 'b',
        c: 'c',
        id: 'id'
      },
      url: "update.php",
      success: function(result) {

      }
    });
  });
});
```

In the update page, I receive data like this

```
id = $_POST["id"];
a = $_POST["a"];
b = $_POST["b"];
c = $_POST["c"];
```

Is it correct or does it have a problem, because that doesn't work.

Comment: what doesn't work ?

Comment: Error messages? Console errors? What does "Doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Your JavaScript doesn't do anything to inspect the HTTP response. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: The PHP has some obvious errors in it, but you should get useful error messages highlighting them.

Comment: @tanaydin — Not even slightly. The client side code is making a form encoded request not a JSON encoded request.

Comment: Do you really not have anything in this statement? `success: function(result) {

      }` - try `success: function(result) { console.log(result); }`

Comment: my page update.php work pefectly when i insert data using another method, now when i try with ajax, itdon't work, so i have Doubt.

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: in console ,i have message that it work perfectly,{message: "devise was updated."}
message: "devise was updated.",but really it wasn'tupdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works very well, but i think you wrote  the strings instead in the variables  'data' object.

```
 var a = $("#a").val();
    var b = $("#b").val();
    var c = $("#c").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        a: a,
        b: b,
        c: c,
        id: id
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and it worked well,
I suggest check the url again

a good job for finding error is adding console.log() to the success part, like this:

```
     url: "update.php", //check it 
      success: function(result) {
           console.log(result);

         // or you can do this instead of console.log(result)
        // alert(result)

       }
```

and also put this state in your php code :

```
<?php
   print_r($_POST);
?>
```

then after clicking on the button you can see the result, on the console of browser